# Transaction instantly rejected trying to send from bitcoin-cli

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, bitcoin-core-accounts

Trying to send bitcoins with this command:
`bitcoin-cli sendfrom accountdos 1HC...kgT 0.03233376 1`

I get this error immediately:
`The transaction was rejected! This might happen if some of the coins in your wallet were already spent, such as if you used a copy of wallet.dat and coins were spent in the copy but not marked as spent here.`

`bitcoin-cli getbalance accountdos 1` returns `0.03464875`

I haven't imported the wallet anywhere else, and my node is synced.

Comment: It may be interesting which version of Bitcoin Core were you using. Note that the "sendfrom" command and accounts in general in Bitcoin Core have been deprecated. The RPC help notes that "Requires wallet passphrase to be set with walletpassphrase call.". I assume that you have done the latter?

Comment: @Murch Currently running Unlimited instead of Core: `/BitcoinUnlimited:1.0.1.2(EB16; AD12)`. I wasn't aware sendfrom and accounts had been deprecated. Is that the case with BU as well? What should I be using instead?

Comment: I don't know about Bitcoin Unlimited, but I would assume that its JSON-RPC would be largely as in Bitcoin Core 0.12, from which it forked. The RPC help states that `sendtoaddress` should be used instead of `sendfrom`, but `sendtoaddress` apparently doesn't let you define which UTXOs to use. TBH, I don't know.